# Objective-c: Making NSArray all lowercased

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

i am having a strange problem when tryin to catch some data on my plist..
so, here is my plist 
[image: plist]

so okay, getting the data is fine, so then i used this code to just you know get the data

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"kurdiebg" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *plistData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"english = %@", self.searchQwery.text];
NSArray *filtered = [plistData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];



NSLog(@"found matches: %@ : %@", filtered,[filtered valueForKey:@"kurdi"]);

if (filtered.count>0) {
    NSDictionary *dic  = filtered[0];
    self.ss.text = dic[@"kurdi"];
}
```

but here to the strange part-- when i try to search for **abbey** (lowercased)it returns the right result, the problem is it has twenty two thousand records they're not all lowercased,
[image: Abbey]

okay, then when i make the first **A** capital, it returns nothing
[image: abbey]

Thanks for even visiting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do case insensitive search by adding `[c]`.
Try this.

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"english ==[c] %@", self.searchQwery.text];
```